# GNOME Extensions doesn't install any extension

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I've tried with the mentioned app, with Edge and with Firefox (`snap` and `apt`). It doesn't tell me what's wrong, it lets me click the *Install* option but it doesn't work. Here are some screenshots:

- First, I search for an extension and then I click on *Install*:

  [image: search for extension and click install]
- Then, I confirm my choice:

  [image: confirm installation]
- And, finally, nothing happened:

  [image: supposedly installed extension]

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1

Comment: It seems that you are trying to install Dash to Plank, which requires Plank to be installed before installing the extension. Did you install Plank? Did you log out and log back in after installing the extension? Also, are you using Wayland? Because Dash to Plank explicitly mentions that it does not work on Wayland.

Comment: Yes, i do have plank installed, but this error happens with all extensions, not just Dash to Plank!

Comment: And i tried with both: Xorg and Wayland.. And nothing